# Delete flanking uppercase characters in a string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line-interface, bioinformatics

How could I remove the uppercases that start and end in this string (DNA sequence) using the linux terminal?

Input:

`TCGTAAATGGTgggggtcagaccctaaggtttccataaagGCTGGtccaaacgcaacttctaattgaatgataaaatactcatgcatgttGTTCGAtaaaacgtaatatttatggcgtgtctacctaccgttccatcttatcgtttaaactttggtacaattctcagttaagtgacgattgctttggaggaagtaatactgtgatcacaatctatgctgtttgcgttgccAAAAAAtttcaatgtaaaaaaaaaTCGAAAATGGT`

Desired Output:

`gggggtcagaccctaaggtttccataaagGCTGGtccaaacgcaacttctaattgaatgataaaatactcatgcatgttGTTCGAtaaaacgtaatatttatggcgtgtctacctaccgttccatcttatcgtttaaactttggtacaattctcagttaagtgacgattgctttggaggaagtaatactgtgatcacaatctatgctgtttgcgttgccAAAAAAtttcaatgtaaaaaaaaa`

Note there are other internal uppercases in the string that must be preserved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sed` with a regular expression:

```
sed -e 's/^[A-Z]*//' -e 's/[A-Z]*$//'
```

(It would also be possible to combine these into a single regex, but I wrote it this way for clarity; the first regex strips leading uppercase chars, the second strips trailing uppercase chars.)

```
[me@localhost ~]$ echo 'TCGTAAATGGTgggggtcagaccctaaggtttccataaagGCTGGtccaaacgcaacttctaattgaatgataaaatactcatgcatgttGTTCGAtaaaacgtaatatttatggcgtgtctacctaccgttccatcttatcgtttaaactttggtacaattctcagttaagtgacgattgctttggaggaagtaatactgtgatcacaatctatgctgtttgcgttgccAAAAAAtttcaatgtaaaaaaaaaTCGAAAATGGT' | sed -e 's/^[A-Z]*//' -e 's/[A-Z]*$//'
gggggtcagaccctaaggtttccataaagGCTGGtccaaacgcaacttctaattgaatgataaaatactcatgcatgttGTTCGAtaaaacgtaatatttatggcgtgtctacctaccgttccatcttatcgtttaaactttggtacaattctcagttaagtgacgattgctttggaggaagtaatactgtgatcacaatctatgctgtttgcgttgccAAAAAAtttcaatgtaaaaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 2):

Using sed you can do this, assuming each string is in one line:

```
sed 's/^[A-Z]*\|[A-Z]*$//g' <<< "$s"
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose

```
sequence=TCGTAAATGGTgggggtcagaccctaaggtttccataaagGCTGGtccaaacgcaacttctaattgaatgataaaatactcatgcatgttGTTCGAtaaaacgtaatatttatggcgtgtctacctaccgttccatcttatcgtttaaactttggtacaattctcagttaagtgacgattgctttggaggaagtaatactgtgatcacaatctatgctgtttgcgttgccAAAAAAtttcaatgtaaaaaaaaaTCGAAAATGGT
```

A pure `bash` requiring extended patterns would be

```
shopt -s extglob
tmp1=${sequence##*([TCGA])}  # Save the result of stripping the leading capitals
echo ${tmp1%%*([TCGA])}      # Strip the trailing capitals
```